# Substitute WCF Endpoint Address in VSTS Release Management

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, release-management

I'm using VSTS to Build and Deploy a Windows Service to several different servers. Within the App.config for my Windows Service I have a reference to a WCF Service that I'm calling:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMobileSyncService">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://192.111.11.111/1.0.0.18/MobileService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMobileService"
    contract="MSSRef.IMobileService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMobileService" />
</client>
```

I'm currently using the same Build for all servers but using the Release Management stage of VSTS to substitute values in my App.config (for example, Connection Strings and server specific values). This is working perfectly.

With reference to the above code example however, how would I substitute the `endpoint address` out for values specific to each server? I'm not sure how to target this specific block in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

There are some extensions that can do it, for example:

[Release Management Utility tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks), related article: [Using Tokenization (Token Replacement) for Builds/Releases in vNext/TFS 2015](https://dustinoprea.com/2016/05/06/using-tokenization-token-replacement-for-buildsreleases-in-tfs-2015/)

[Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

You also can do it programming through PowerShell.

Comment: Using Tokenization worked form me like a charm. It replaces tokens by variables set on release pipelines. Variables values can vary inside release, if scope of the value is set to the stage instead.